# Does MegaRAID support creation of initially degraded RAID array?

Tags: raid, megaraid, megacli, megaraid-storage-manager

I want to make a RAID5 array out of 3 disks, copy data from the one disk I have then clear it and add as a spare to the array. A similar magic I can do in linux with `mdadm` utility (`mdadm --create drv1 drv2 drv3 missing` & `mdadm --add drv4`). I have a cloud backup so the possible risk of failure during the operation is fine.

Is this trick possible with MegaRaid controllers (and the 9271-8i in particular)?

The other option would be to make a RAID1 and then migrate it to RAID5 but it seams to by slower and troublesome way to go...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create degraded raid6 array using megacli](https://serverfault.com/questions/780790/how-to-create-degraded-raid6-array-using-megacli)

Comment: @shodanshok yes, most likely. There is a slight hope that they do have this functionality hidden somewhere in the native interface, but there's not much hope already.